# Is that possible to develop iPhone apps without using interface builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I mean if I can build all the iPhone apps without interface builder? If yes, where can I find some stuff about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed (see Roman's answer), but the real question is - why.

IB is a very powerful tool, that helps you put together UI's very quickly.  The way it works is different than most other GUI developers, in that it's not generating code for you - instead it's like you are assembling live objects and setting properties on them, then freezing them for later.  Once you have the "thawed" objects it's easy to do further manipulation.

One good example is UILabel - in code you are going to be setting several properties, never mind the frame to make use of a label - whereas in IB you can have multiple labels on a page in seconds with custom font and appearance settings.

So what are you hoping to gain from not using IB?  Just be sure you are making that choice for the right reasons.

Comment: One "why" answer, and the reason I rarely use IB, is when interfaces have to be completely dynamic. It's just easier to create the interface dynamically in one place, as opposed to first creating all the elements in the xib, then programatically figuring out the positioning, then moving everything around.

Comment: Actually I disagree with that.  Even when interfaces need to be totally dynamic, it can often be easier to build sections of the UI in IB, and properly define the autoresizing behaviors so that the UI components can adapt to available size.

Comment: I agree with Eric, though I am new to iPhone development. I just think it would be easier to control the "visual objects" in code. And IB just provides an "visual way" to create and initialize the "visual objects"(am I correct?). I'd like doing the same thing the "code way"

Answer (score 2):

[Tutorial on NOT using Interface Builder for iPhone GUI design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616456/tutorial-on-not-using-interface-builder-for-iphone-gui-design)

Comment: Thank you and I am going to check that out

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [phoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) . You build iphone apps using regular html, css + javascript.

Comment: I am not supposed to use that cause it may have some limits. Thank you still