# creating an iPhone app without using the Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

I'm looking into creating a simple iPhone app without using the interface builder, i.e. without creating the XIB files.

I've succeed so far in showing the main window and changing the background color, but i'm looking into adding UITextfield, UILabel, and a button. and then connect them to methods that i've created before.

is there any good tutorial or a reference that I can use?

Thank you very much

Comment: There are plenty of guides and questions on this. Please search before asking.

Comment: I've been searching for a whole day, and no clear answer showing a way on how to do that

Comment: One search, http://designthencode.com/scratch/, http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7767-programming-without-interface-builder.html, http://blog.cjgammon.com/?p=17, http://www.longyiqi.com/blog/ios/2011/09/12/programming-without-interface-builder/. There are plenty more.

Comment: Thank you! that looks helpful. All I found were links talking about WITH XIB. and some others were just very basic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial on NOT using Interface Builder for iPhone GUI design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616456/tutorial-on-not-using-interface-builder-for-iphone-gui-design)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read Apple's documentation. For example, to create a `UILabel` programmatically, read the [UILabel Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html). First instantiate it

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

Then set it up as you like, e.g.

```
[label setText:@"My label now has text!"];
```

Then add it to the view

```
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Then move it around, etc. For more help, first google "create uilabel programmatically", then, if you get stuck, post a specific question here.